# Passing cucumber @Tags without overwriting allure runner cucumber options in pom.xml

Tags: maven, allure

The following option **must** be specified inside the pom.xml it is not supported from the commandline:

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar            
                     -Dcucumber.options="--plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureReporter"
            </argLine>
```

However, I also need to pass in a list of tags that I wish to run, how can I do that? it works if i provide them from a .bat file but it will **overwrite** the allure plugin already set in the pom.xml, can I append to it rather than overwrite it?

**Bat file:**

```
call mvn clean
call mvn -Dbrowser=chrome -Drun.on.browserstack.grid.local=local [insert way to pass tags to run here without overwriting pom.xml allure plugin value] test
```

I can make it run the tags I want but then it is not using the allure runner and thus, results are not generated because I have overwritten the cucumber options by specifying it in the bat file